# Embedded file system and sqlite

Tags: sqlite, embedded, filesystems

I'm working on an embedded project that has no file system, and our kludge of a database has ballooned in functionality.  It's now so inefficient, we can't stand it any longer.

I'm trying to figure out if there's built-in support for a flat file system in SQLite.  I've dug around http://sqlite.org for a while now, but haven't found anything specifically covering it.  Has anyone found a supported implementation written in C?  It seems like such a straightforward request, but I can't find anything written about it.

We have plenty of memory available.  In a perfect world, I'd like to just set aside a large portion of it, pass the FS a pointer, then let the FS/SQLite library just use what it wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement an SQLite [Virtual File System](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/vfs.html) for your non-volatile memory.